# Iterator inside for-loop: why is this not working?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iterator

I have this piece of code, it's not working and I have no idea why.

My data structure:

- "genes" is a dictionary with as key it's ID, as value multiple
  instances of the object Gene.
- the Gene object contains a similar dictionary with instances of the
  object "Transcript".

Finally, "parent" is an ID of a Transcript (string).
I need to get the Transcript instance (ptrans) which has the same ID as the string "parent".
It is inside one of the Gene instances.

When I am running the code at the bottom, I don't get a real exception, but a "StopIteration", which I thought I catch, whereafter it should continue with the next Gene object, right?:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ...
    ptrans = next(t for t in g.transcripts.values() if t.ID == parent)
StopIteration`

I could do it with a nested for-loop, but I though this might work aswell. I just can't get my head around the fact that this does not work. Can anyone explain why, or how it might work?

```
    # iterate over Gene-dict
    for g in genes.values(): 
        #Iterate over Transcripts in 1 Gene
        try:
            ptrans = next(t for t in g.transcripts.values() if t.ID == parent)
        #If no match, continue
        except StopIteration:
            continue
        if ptrans:
                break
```

Comment: It looks like you should be catching it. Can you post a [minimal runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem when run? It seems like you may have hidden the cause of the error when stripping down your code and traceback.

Comment: Your traceback doesn't show the `try` block your code has.

Comment: Why are you doing the break there? The break will stop the for loop so it looks like it will stop once it's successfully run once. Is that intentional?

Comment: continue "cuts off" the current iteration and starts at the next item. So if ptrans gets defined, there's no StopIteration, meaning that it has found the ID, whereafter it can break out of the for-loop.

Comment: `next()` has an optional [second parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), which means that you could do `if next(iter, None) is None` rather than catching the `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: The strange thing is, when I tried to make the minimal runnable example, suddenly this code is working? The error must be somewhere else I guess. As holdenweb is saying below, will do with nested loop again.

Comment: Actually, in constrast to holdenweb, I see no issue with what you are doing (and the minimal example seems to work fine, as you said). For those unused to it, it's just a way to implement single-line custom search algorithms with shortcut (they stop on the first hit, unlike a list comprehension version, which would search everything). Joel's solution (`next(iter, None)`) is definitely preferable to an exception though.

Comment: Implemented that. It works now after I removed the try/except. I don't see a logical difference, but I guess python does ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
ptrans = next(t for t in g.transcripts.values() if t.ID == parent)
```

almost certainly isn't doing what you think. I suspect that there are no items in `g.transcript.values()` that have the parent as their ID, since calling `next()` on an empty generator would indeed raise a `StopIteration` error.

The `next()` function, however, will in any case only be called once, meaning that even if there *are* valid values only the first one would ever be returned. Nested loops are a much simpler way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I already got that in v1, but I though this way would be more elegant.

Comment: Why? I'd say elegance in code should begin with correct operation. I applaud your desire to learn, but you have a little way to go still with generators.

Comment: @holdenweb - Actually, I use that kind of construction all the time. It's a fancy way to implement a custom find algorithm in a single line. He's only looking for the first instance anyways (and, it sounds like, only expecting a single one at all).

Comment: The ID's are unique, so yes, there is only one transcript which I'm expecting to retrieve. But I guess then there is a mistake in my code elsewhere.